# How to use the jsf ?faces-redirect=true behind a apache proxy

Tags: apache, jsf, redirect

I have an apache on port 80 as a proxy with this setting:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://domain.com:8080/myapp
```

On port 8080 is a glassfish 4.0 server running.

I want to use the ?faces-redirect=true function ([Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)), to see always the right url after submitting a form. (Or something similar).

After a click on a button on

```
domain.com/myapp/page.xhtml
```

I want to go to

```
domain.com/myapp/page2.xhtml
```

But Java/JSF redirects me to domain.com:**8080**/myapp/page2.xhtml

How can I say, that the redirection should go to domain.com/myapp/page2.xhtml on port 80?

Comment: Do you also have a `ProxyPassReverse`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have both a ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse with the same parameters

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://domain.com:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://domain.com:8080/myapp
```